# ListView - setOnItemClickListener not working

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to implement a listview with a custom adapter. The problem is that it crashes whenever a onItemClickListener event is triggered.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: imp.translator.diana.lang.CardItemData
>   cannot be cast to java.lang.String
>               at imp.translator.diana.lang.Speak$1.onItemClick(Speak.java:41)
>               at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick

This is my class:

```
    final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

    list.addHeaderView(new View(this));
    list.addFooterView(new View(this));

    BaseInflaterAdapter<CardItemData> adapter = new BaseInflaterAdapter<CardItemData>(new CardInflater());

    CardItemData data = new CardItemData("Translate");
    adapter.addItem(data, false);
    CardItemData data2 = new CardItemData("Voice to Text");
    adapter.addItem(data2, false);
    CardItemData data3 = new CardItemData("Record");
    adapter.addItem(data3, false);
    CardItemData data4 = new CardItemData("Info");
    adapter.addItem(data4, false);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setClickable(true);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView myAdapter, View myView, int position, long mylng) {
            String selectedFromList = (String) (myAdapter.getItemAtPosition(position));
        }
    });
```

and my adapter:

```
public class BaseInflaterAdapter<T> extends BaseAdapter
{
    private List<T> m_items = new ArrayList<T>();
    private IAdapterViewInflater<T> m_viewInflater;

    public BaseInflaterAdapter(IAdapterViewInflater<T> viewInflater)
    {
        m_viewInflater = viewInflater;
    }

    public BaseInflaterAdapter(List<T> items, IAdapterViewInflater<T> viewInflater)
    {
        m_items.addAll(items);
        m_viewInflater = viewInflater;
    }

    public void setViewInflater(IAdapterViewInflater<T> viewInflater, boolean notifyChange)
    {
        m_viewInflater = viewInflater;

        if (notifyChange)
            notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addItem(T item, boolean notifyChange)
    {
        m_items.add(item);

        if (notifyChange)
            notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addItems(List<T> items, boolean notifyChange)
    {
        m_items.addAll(items);

        if (notifyChange)
            notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void clear(boolean notifyChange)
    {
        m_items.clear();

        if (notifyChange)
            notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return m_items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos)
    {
        return getTItem(pos);
    }

    public T getTItem(int pos)
    {
        return m_items.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos)
    {
        return pos;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        return m_viewInflater != null ? m_viewInflater.inflate(this, pos, convertView, parent) : null;
    }
}
```

and the CardItemData:

```
public class CardItemData
{
    private String m_text1;
    public CardItemData(String text1)
    {
        m_text1 = text1;
    }
    public String getText1()
    {
        return m_text1;
    }
}
```

Any idea what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.lang.ClassCastException: imp.translator.diana.lang.CardItemData
>   cannot be cast to java.lang.String

the above exception was due to 
`String selectedFromList = (String) (myAdapter.getItemAtPosition(position));` here you are try to convert `CardItemData` into `String`

try this:

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView myAdapter, View myView, int position, long mylng) {
                CardItemData selectedFromList = (CardItemData) (myAdapter.getItemAtPosition(position)); 
                String pos = selectedFromList.getText1();
            }
        });
```

Comment: it didn't work that way, it said "cannot resolve symbol";
changed it to this 
CardItemData selectedFromList = (CardItemData) (myAdapter.getItemAtPosition(position));
String pos = selectedFromList.getText1();and it works now. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea what might be wrong here?

your `getItem` is returning `T` which is, in your case, an instance of `CardItemData`, but here:

```
 String selectedFromList = (String) (myAdapter.getItemAtPosition(position));
```

you are casting it to `String`. You probably want to cast it to `CardItemData`. Btw, Java supports covariant return types, so you should be able to use

```
@Override
public T getItem(int pos) {
    return m_items.get(pos);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a typecast issue, you are type casting " CardItemData " to " String "

String selectedFromList = (String) (myAdapter.getItemAtPosition(position));

use "getItem" method to get clicked " CardItemData " item.

Check the link given below
[Android Docs link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html)